# Why is only my Git for Windows slow when I'm not on my company's domain?

Tags: windows, git, performance, dns, git-bash

My Git for Windows (Win10) is slow with everything: starting Git Bash (20 secs), executing commands like `cd` or even a mere return; 6 seconds after each command). But, this is only when I work at home with the laptop (no VPN), Git works fine on the same laptop when I'm at the office (a Windows Domain). My colleagues do not experience these lags at home with their laptops, but I found out they never shut down their computers. I tried the same, and then Git isn't slow. So, what might cause the lag when I restart my laptop at home?

My `.gitconfig` does not contain UNCs.
Git garbage collecting did not help.
I reinstalled Git, the latest version (2.12.2.windows.2).

Oh, and my edits show different names for who edited in BitBucket when working at home (mailadres) or at the office (user@domain).

Comment: Well is anything else slow on your home computer?

Comment: No other program is slow, except SourceTree, which is merely the GUI to Git.

Comment: Oh, and I meant that it's the same laptop that I use. At work Git works fine, at home slow.

Comment: What parts of git are slow? Is, say, `git checkout` slow? Can you give some examples of operations that you feel are slow, and some indication of what "slow" and "fast" means? Such as "If I do a `git checkout` at work it takes 1 second but at home it takes 10 seconds", etc.

Comment: Startup of Git Bash is slow (20 sec), before the bash is shown. 
And there's a lag after each command. Even a mere Return takes about 6 secs before bash is there again. The info for Git Status is displayed quite fast and smooth, but the bash takes at least 6 secs.

Comment: Following up on Lasse's comments, maybe the connection which Git is using to the remote repository is slow for some reason.

Comment: Sound plausible for part of the delays, but does a Return in Git Bash make a call to the remote repository? It's my guess it does not. How could I check if it calls the remote repository?

Comment: having the same problem, when my laptop can't reach the domain controller git is very slow

Comment: Same issue here. All git commands takes a lot more time to complete through VPN, while it works just fine from the office. This is not a network speed/latency issue. Feels like a timeout, somehow.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Well, yes, in fact! Some time ago it changed into acceptable speed, and I cannot think of anything I changed that might have caused this. So, case closed, I guess...